# IE8 flex not triggering focusOut event

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer-8

I have a textfield in flex with a focusOut event on it. I can type in the box and in Firefox and Chrome when I click elsewhere on the page (outside the flash element) the focusOut event will be triggered. However in IE8, the texfield never loses focus when you click elsewhere on the page, outside the flash object. I've tried with focusManager.browserMode set to true and false with no difference (I believe that effects incoming focus anyway). Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

check if your application becomes deactivated when the user clicks outside